# Htaccess redirect to one url to another url

Tags: php, .htaccess

**I want to redirect url like below**

URL: www.domain.com/en/events/952ls5xs7206

Redirect to https://www.domain.com/en/events/952ls5xs7206

I tried below code in **.htaccess file** but not working.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on

RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

Answer (score 0):

**your code from above should work. everything is fine :)** 
you have to be sure `mod_rewrite` is **activated** in your `php.ini`
if your on linux you can activate it with `a2enmod rewrite`

and then try something like this and put it at top of your `.htaccess` file

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R,L]
```

or with php you can force it like:

```
// Force HTTPS for security
if($_SERVER["HTTPS"] != "on") {
 $pageURL = "Location: https://";
 if ($_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] != "80") {
  $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"] . ":" . $_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] . $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
 } else {
  $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"] . $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
 }
 header($pageURL);
}
```